# Asp put query into array and go through it without refreshing page

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, vb.net, informix

How would I go about running a query in asp and storing it in an array.  Then with the array go through each record without having to refresh the page every time.

for example

```
Sub loaddata()
    Dim conn As New IfxConnection(connectionstring)

    Dim results() As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring
    Try
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("Made connection!")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Dim cmd As New IfxCommand("Select name from table", conn)
    Dim reader As IfxDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    While reader.Read()
        results(i) = reader("name")
        i += 1

    End While
    reader.Close()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

The results are stored in results(i)

Say I have a button that says next and everytime I want it to go to the next item in the results array.  I don't want the page to refresh.  How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider how you are going to set up your page. There are many ways to go about doing this.

If you get all the records on the page load, you can then assign them to their respective controls. To make it appear is if they are on many pages you could use a MultiView control.

**Markup**

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
   <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server"> 
      <asp:Label ID="lblRecordOne" runat="server" />
   </asp:View>
   <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server"> 
      <asp:Label ID="lblRecordTwo" runat="server" />
   </asp:View>         
</asp:MultiView>
<asp:Button ID="btNext" runat="server">Next</asp:Button>
```

**Code-behind**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     'Call your method that loads the data to results
     Dim results() As String = loaddata()
     'Set the data
     lblRecordOne.Text = results(0)
     lblRecordTwo.Text = results(1)
End Sub

Protected Sub btNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btNext.Click

 'There is a much better way to go about this, but for this 
 'demos sake here is the basic idea
 MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2)

End Sub
```

What you want to keep in mind is that each View control has an index inside of the MultiView. So you need a way to keep track of what the active view is. When the user clicks the next button you progress the view by one.

**In terms of an MVC application**

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController 
{
   // /Home/GetRecord/{id}
   public ViewResult GetRecord(int? id)
   {
        int modelID;
        if (id == null) { modelID = 0; }
        ViewBag.CurrentID = modelID;
        // This will send the value to the view
        // I would refactor loaddata to only return one record at a time
        // based on an id or an index
        return View(loaddata(modelID));
   }
}
```

**View**

```
<label>@Model.Result</label>
@Html.ActionLink("GetRecord", "Home", new { id = ViewBag.CurrentID + 1 })
```

Every time you click on the ActionLink it will progress through the record set by one.

If the first record is Hello and the second record is World:

/Home/GetRecord/0 - Hello

/Home/GetRecord/1 - World

Sorry that I switched it up to C#, I prefer writing C# by free hand rather than VB. The code is very similar in VB. If you need a converter to go http://converter.telerik.com/.

Comment: so say I have 1000 records I need to create 1000 things like    <asp:Label ID="lblRecordTwo" runat="server" /> ?

Comment: If you have a 1000 records and you want to display one per page, then a MultiView is definitely not the tool for this case. I would strongly recommend using an MVC application.

In an MVC application you can set up a controller that has a method that retrieves a record by an id. Then the URL will be like this /Home/GetRecord/1. The number at the end of the URL will indicate what record to get. I will update my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should render the result in a control, or a variable using RegisterClientScript, and control the navigation by javascript

Comment: I am really new to asp and web stuff in general.. Do you have an example?